# How to add an image to Media Library with Sitecore Rocks

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-rocks

How do I add an image to the Media Library in Sitecore Rocks?

I tried following the instructions [here](http://vsplugins.sitecore.net/Uploading-Media-Items.ashx):

> Drag an image file from your Windows Explorer to the Sitecore Explorer. When you hit an item in the Media Library, the mouse cursor becomes enabled.

But I got some sort of `cursor: not-allowed` type of symbol when I tried dragging images into the folder.

<sub>P.S.: I'm not kidding.</sub>

Comment: I also tried few days ago to add multiple files in Media library but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have started Visual Studio using the `Run as Administrator` option (which is common to allow you to debug using the `Attach to Process` option) then the issue is the mismatch of permissions between the Visual Studio instance and the Windows Explorer instance, which will be running as the logged in user.

Try running Visual Studio as the logged in user and it will work, or right click on the Media Library folder and use the Upload Media option.

[image: Rocks Upload Media]

Alternatively, drop your files into the `/upload` folder of the website so that they are uploaded [automatically using the Media File Watcher](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/mass-uploading-media/).

**EDIT:**

Make sure you are connection is set up to use the Hard Rock Web Service and *not* the Good Old Web Service since the Upload Media option will not be available using the legacy connector.

Comment: Ran Visual Studio 2013 as Administrator, but I'm not seeing an option called `Upload Media...`.

Comment: You don't need to run VS as administrator to see the option. Make sure you are connection is set up to use the `Hard Rock Web Service` and *not* the `Good Old Web Service` since it will not work with that.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick.  Can you please make note of the `Hard Rock Web Service` vs. `Good Old Web Service` bit in your answer so I can mark the question as answered?  Also, where is it actually documented that you cannot upload media using `Good Old Web Service`?

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work using the legacy connector unfortunately. It's always best to use the Hard Rock Web Service whenever possible.